# "Could not map the MEP URI" Error from Axis2/c and Rampart

Tags: web-services, apache, apache-axis, rampart

I had my web services working. I introduced rampart and now I am getting an error in response. The Webserver is Apache httpd. Running Axis2/c with Rampart 1.3.0. The services.xml looks correct as far as I can tell but I can post that too if needed. The MEP in the services.xml is the correct one which is http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out

This is my Request from SoapUI. It's very basic.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:itr="http://../WS/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>a</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">6AkYWCxaCOoiBT7QqLC/R0bIM68=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">qKcdLrqAOYsZojFzapXDdg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2011-09-29T16:05:59.146Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <itr:GetEquipmentRoot/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response I get in SoapUI:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Could not map the MEP URI to an Axis2/C MEP constant value</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the Axis Log:

```
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_util.c(32) [rampart]Trying to load module AuthenticatorCallBack.dll
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\util\src\class_loader.c(140) AuthenticatorCallBack.dll shared lib loaded successfully
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_util.c(48) [rampart]Successfully loaded module AuthenticatorCallBack.dll
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_header_processor.c(1815) [rampart]Processing security header in Strict layout
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_header_processor.c(1824) [rampart]Processing security header element UsernameToken
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [info]  [rampart]Validating UsernameToken
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_processed_result.c(48) [rampart]Set SPR_UT_nonce in Security Processed Results of message context 
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_processed_result.c(48) [rampart]Set SPR_UT_created in Security Processed Results of message context 
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_processed_result.c(48) [rampart]Set SPR_UT_username in Security Processed Results of message context 
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_processed_result.c(48) [rampart]Set SPR_UT_passwordType in Security Processed Results of message context 
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [info]  [rampart]Password comparison SUCCESS
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_processed_result.c(48) [rampart]Set SPR_UT_Checked in Security Processed Results of message context 
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [info]  [rampart]Validating UsernameToken SUCCESS
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_header_processor.c(1824) [rampart]Processing security header element (null)
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_header_processor.c(1908) [rampart]Unknown security header (null)
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\util\rampart_sec_header_processor.c(1915) [rampart](null) processing failed
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\handlers\rampart_in_handler.c(143) [rampart][rampart_in_handler] Security Header processing failed.
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\core\engine\phase.c(233) Handler RampartInHandler invoke failed within phase Security
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\core\engine\engine.c(696) Invoking phase Security failed
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\core\engine\engine.c(279) Invoking operation specific phases failed for operation GetEquipmentRoot
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [debug] ..\..\src\core\engine\phase.c(210) Invoke the handler RampartOutHandler within the phase MessageOut
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\util\rampart_engine.c(159) [rampart][rampart_engine] Cannot get saved rampart_context
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\handlers\rampart_out_handler.c(136) [rampart][rampart_out_handler] ramaprt_context creation failed.
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\core\engine\phase.c(233) Handler RampartOutHandler invoke failed within phase MessageOut
[Thu Sep 29 10:00:16 2011] [error] ..\..\src\core\engine\engine.c(696) Invoking phase MessageOut failed
```

I cannot figure out this one issue.

Answer (score 0):

can u publish your WSDL file too? Basically in your WSDL file, did you specify MEP information to operations?